# Can I get openapi3 referenced schema properties with vertx 4.0.0?

Tags: vert.x, openapi

I can get the openapi3 operation model [as described in the documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-openapi/java/#_operation_model),
but I would like to get the referenced schema properties.

for example I have the "post-example" operation in my yaml:

```
  /post-example:
    post:
      summary: Example for all the possible 200 query responses
      operationId: post-example
      tags:
        - read
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          "application/json":
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/example-query"
      responses:
        200:
          description: Expected response to a valid request
```

and I would like to get the "example-query" schema properties.

Is this possible with vertx 4.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

Using `RouterBuilder#getOpenAPI()` you can get the `OpenAPIHolder`, which allows you to access to any component of the OpenAPI document using `JsonPointer`:

```
OpenAPIHolder holder = routerBuilder.getOpenAPI();
Object schema = holder.getCached(
  JsonPointer.from("#/components/schemas/example-query")
);
```